# Error when running heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm currently going through the Railstutorial and keep getting an error when I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

I already searched online for hours - the error seems common but none of the proposed solutions seem to make any difference, your help would be very much appreciated!

The error is

```
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

I ran `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` and changed my gemfile, it now looks like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.0'
end

group :production do
   gem "pg"
end
```

After committing I ran `bundle install --without production` and `git push heroku`

my database.yml looks like this:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: what do you have in your database.yml file?

Comment: added database.yml in original post

Comment: take out the production group in your gemfile and run bundle install

Comment: solved it - I was using older version of rails and gems according to the 1st edition of railstutorials. Seems there was a bug in one of them. The newer version according to the 2nd edition seem to work fine. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle install` and then push to heroku

Omit the `--without production` so you gemfile.lock can get actualize with gem pg

Comment: alright, ran `bundle install` , `git push heroku` , `heroku run rake db:migrate` - same error. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: after runing bundle install, are you saving the changes with git? "git add ." then "git commit -m "actualize gemfile""

Comment: yes, I did. Just to be sure I deleted gemfile.lock, ran `bundle install`, `git add .` , `git commit -am` and pushed, still same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same error using a windows system. Tried it on a Ubunto virtual machine and for some reason the error vanished as I was able

Comment: Could you leave a full answer? Perhaps completing the last sentence would help.